# How to bind the storage blob name dynamically from a particular field inside trigger queue message

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobssdk

I am trying to do some logging for a triggered message(queue), so that if a message fails and it gets picked up by the webjob next time I would have logged some information so that I wouldn't redo the success paths(like sending messages to clients after stage1).
So I plan on using the azure blob storage binding to configure as input and output streams. But in order to do it i need a unique name for the blob. I have a guid inside the message and i plan on using that guid to read/write from the blob storage.
How do i configure this blob storage name binding dynamically from a guid field inside the queue message. (My message is very big and i don't want to use the entire message as a blob storage name).

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%testQueue%")],
TestMessageModel testMessage,
[Blob("testStorage/{queueTrigger}", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] Stream logstream)
{

}
```

As you can see, the official documentation only uses queueTrigger that uses the string inside the message as the blob name. But my message looks big like this

```
public class TestMessageModel
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public int FromOrg {get; set;}
  public DateTime BatchDate {get; set;}
  public Payments[] payments {get; set;}  // this array is big (many items)
}
```

I don't want to use something that ridiculous as a blob name.
how to use the Id inside the testMessage?

Comment: Use CloudBlobContainer instead of Stream in your code. So that you can manually create a blockblob and set its name. Answer added. Please have a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jack Jia. That helped. But for the webjob I needed to use Blob before to bind it properly.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("%testQueue%")],
TestMessageModel testMessage,
[Blob("testStorage")] CloudBlobContainer blobContainer)
{
   CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(testmessage.id+".txt");
}
```

Comment: Great. I am glad that it helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an output integration with Storage Blob. And set the path value as the container name.

[image]

2. In your function code, you can directly use the container, and create a blob with specific name (which you can get from your queue message):

[image]

3. Finally, you will be able to see the blob with specific name in your target container.

[image]

Documentation for your reference:
[Storage Blob Output Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---usage)